# How can I disable the defaul aspnet core config change watcher?

Tags: docker, configuration-files, asp.net-core-2.1, filesystemwatcher

I have an ASPNET core application running in a Docker container. I currently cannot start more than 64 containers ([initially described here](https://superuser.com/questions/1437500/is-docker-limited-to-64-running-containers-per-image)) of the image I have created.

By running the container interactively I found this error during the startup phase.

> Unhandled Exception: System.IO.IOException: The configured user limit (128) on the number of inotify instances has been reached.
>
> at System.IO.FileSystemWatcher.StartRaisingEvents()
>      at System.IO.FileSystemWatcher.StartRaisingEventsIfNotDisposed()
>      at System.IO.FileSystemWatcher.set_EnableRaisingEvents(Boolean value)
>      at Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders.Physical.PhysicalFilesWatcher.TryEnableFileSystemWatcher()
>      at Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders.Physical.PhysicalFilesWatcher.CreateFileChangeToken(String filter)
>      at Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders.PhysicalFileProvider.Watch(String filter)
>      at Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileConfigurationProvider.<.ctor>b__0_0()
>
> at Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives.ChangeToken.OnChange(Func`1 changeTokenProducer, Action changeTokenConsumer)
>      at Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileConfigurationProvider..ctor(FileConfigurationSource source)
>      at Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json.JsonConfigurationSource.Build(IConfigurationBuilder builder)
>      at Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.ConfigurationBuilder.Build()
>      at
>
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.WebHostBuilder.BuildCommonServices(AggregateException& hostingStartupErrors)
>      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.WebHostBuilder.Build()
>      at MyProjectName.Program.Main(String[] args) in /src/MyProjectName/Program.cs:line 10

`Program.cs` only has the default content

```
 1 using Microsoft.AspNetCore;
 2 using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
 3
 4 namespace CmcIiiCgiSim
 5 {
 6    public class Program
 7    {
 8        public static void Main(string[] args)
 9        {
10            CreateWebHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
11        }
12
13        public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
14            WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
15                .UseStartup<Startup>();
16     }
17 }
```

It appears that watching for configuration changes is a default setting of ASP or rather any ASPNET core app ([see MS documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/aspnet/core/fundamentals/change-tokens?view=aspnetcore-2.2#additional-resources))

My question is: How can I disable this option in the *settings* for the *existing* configuration files?
In the hope that this will also disable the filesystem watcher and get rid of the error.

I have found quite a few examples that state how it can be done programmatically for additional setting files. But in my case the configuration will not change and I'd rather have an image that is not limited to 64 containers.

Comment: The only config that is watched by default is JSON (`appsettings.json` and `appsettings.{environment}.json`). The method to include that config has a param to enable reload or not.

Comment: What I understand from this comment is, that there is in deed _no_ way to do this in the configuration. Is that right?

Comment: Where'd you get that? Set reload to false, and that disables the watcher.

Comment: How? I'm totally dumbstruck here?

Answer (score 4):

I've managed to disable watching on json files (on linux) using the default builder with the following snippet:

```csharp
IWebHostBuilder builder = WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder();

builder.ConfigureAppConfiguration((context, config) =>
{
    foreach (var s in config.Sources)
    {
        if (s is FileConfigurationSource)
            ((FileConfigurationSource)s).ReloadOnChange = false;
    }
});
```

Now the system is not running out of inotify handles anymore.

Comment: This notifies the app about any changes in root folder where the configs are suposed to be. But for some reason it also notify about any changes in all subdirectories. I found out that there are some string allocations by the Filewatcher, but didnt know why, since I dont use it anywhere. 
It turned out that it fired very frequentry, because it was triggered by changes in root/Logs/... and the FileSystemWatcher created has IncludeSubdirectories = true; by default, so it compared the path of changed logfile to the config files every time something was logged. Anyway, this solution fixed it.

Comment: @Ihatemybrainsometimes.. did you found a way to set `IncludeSubdirectories = false` ? Have the same issue and it overloads with my directory having thousands of data files. Like why it wants to watch everything...

Answer (score 3):

The default builder is extremely opinionated and loads the appsettings with the reload already set.  There isn't a way to replace the configuration that was set up in the default builder.  As of .NET Core 3.1.7, this is the CreateDefaultBuilder method with the flags changed to stop the reload.  I've run a server with this configuration and confirmed that no FileSystemWatchers are created.

```cs
    public static IHostBuilder CreateDefaultBuilder(string[] args)
        {
            HostBuilder hostBuilder = new HostBuilder();
            hostBuilder.UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory());
            hostBuilder.ConfigureHostConfiguration((Action<IConfigurationBuilder>) (config =>
            {
                config.AddEnvironmentVariables("DOTNET_");
                config.AddCommandLine(args);
            }));
            hostBuilder.ConfigureAppConfiguration((hostingContext, config) =>
                {
                    IHostEnvironment hostingEnvironment = hostingContext.HostingEnvironment;
                    config.AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", true, false)
                        .AddJsonFile("appsettings." + hostingEnvironment.EnvironmentName + ".json", true, false);
                    if (hostingEnvironment.IsDevelopment() &&
                        !string.IsNullOrEmpty(hostingEnvironment.ApplicationName))
                    {
                        Assembly assembly = Assembly.Load(new AssemblyName(hostingEnvironment.ApplicationName));
                        if (assembly != null)
                            config.AddUserSecrets(assembly, true);
                    }

                    config.AddEnvironmentVariables();
                    config.AddCommandLine(args);
                })
                .ConfigureLogging((hostingContext, logging) =>
                {
                    int num = RuntimeInformation.IsOSPlatform(OSPlatform.Windows) ? 1 : 0;
                    if (num != 0)
                        logging.AddFilter<EventLogLoggerProvider>(level => level >= LogLevel.Warning);
                    logging.AddConfiguration(hostingContext.Configuration.GetSection("Logging"));
                    logging.AddConsole();
                    logging.AddDebug();
                    logging.AddEventSourceLogger();
                    if (num == 0)
                        return;
                    logging.AddEventLog();
                })
                .UseDefaultServiceProvider((Action<HostBuilderContext, ServiceProviderOptions>) ((context, options) =>
                {
                    bool flag = context.HostingEnvironment.IsDevelopment();
                    options.ValidateScopes = flag;
                    options.ValidateOnBuild = flag;
                }));
            return hostBuilder;
        }
```

The key part to this is the calls to `AddJsonFile`. The third parameter being passed as `false`, disabling the file system watcher.

Answer (score 3):

For dotnet 5+ (for sure 5 and 6), you can use the config key `hostBuilder:reloadConfigOnChange` to disable the file watchers. You can [see where it's used](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/v6.0.5/src/libraries/Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting/src/HostingHostBuilderExtensions.cs#L203) in dotnet 6.0.5.

I use environment variables for config, so I added this env var:

```
ASPNETCORE_hostBuilder__reloadConfigOnChange=false
```

I have an amd64 linux ubuntu docker container that runs a dotnet 6 app built with an x64 runtime identifier. I'm running this x86 container on macos aarch64 (apple silicon). The default host builder sets up a bunch of file watchers. Those file watchers use a file watching api that isn't implemented on my hacky cross-platform setup, and so they fail. The stack trace I get is like:

```
at System.IO.FileSystemWatcher.StartRaisingEvents()
at System.IO.FileSystemWatcher.StartRaisingEventsIfNotDisposed()
at System.IO.FileSystemWatcher.set_EnableRaisingEvents(Boolean value)
at Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders.Physical.PhysicalFilesWatcher.TryEnableFileSystemWatcher()
at Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders.Physical.PhysicalFilesWatcher.CreateFileChangeToken(String filter)
at Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders.PhysicalFileProvider.Watch(String filter)
at Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileConfigurationProvider.<.ctor>b__1_0()
at Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives.ChangeToken.OnChange(Func`1 changeTokenProducer, Action changeTokenConsumer)
at Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileConfigurationProvider..ctor(FileConfigurationSource source)
at Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json.JsonConfigurationSource.Build(IConfigurationBuilder builder)
at Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AddSource(IConfigurationSource source)
at Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.IConfigurationBuilder.Add(IConfigurationSource source)
at Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.ConfigurationExtensions.Add[TSource](IConfigurationBuilder builder, Action`1 configureSource)
at Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.JsonConfigurationExtensions.AddJsonFile(IConfigurationBuilder builder, IFileProvider provider, String path, Boolean optional, Boolean reloadOnChange)
at Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.JsonConfigurationExtensions.AddJsonFile(IConfigurationBuilder builder, String path, Boolean optional, Boolean reloadOnChange)
at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostingHostBuilderExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass11_0.<ConfigureDefaults>b__1(HostBuilderContext hostingContext, IConfigurationBuilder config)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.BootstrapHostBuilder.RunDefaultCallbacks(ConfigurationManager configuration, HostBuilder innerBuilder)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.WebApplicationBuilder..ctor(WebApplicationOptions options, Action`1 configureDefaults)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.WebApplication.CreateBuilder(WebApplicationOptions options)
```

More about:

- The [reloadConfigOnChange](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/generic-host?view=aspnetcore-6.0#disable-app-configuration-reload-on-change) config key
- [Runtime identifiers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/rid-catalog#linux-rids)